# Vulkan: `vkFlushMappedMemoryRanges` threading layer error?

Tags: c++, vulkan

If an entire `vkDeviceMemory` is mapped (via `vkMapMemory`) and it wasn't allocated with `VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT`, `vkFlushMappedMemoryRanges` must be made after any modifications to the buffer are made, for the device to see the writes (per the documentation).

I am only modifying small sections of a large buffer, and thus, only want to flush the affected regions. So, I create multiple `VkMappedMemoryRange` structures, with varying `offset` and `size` fields, but pointing to the same `vkDeviceMemory`. This all seems to work as I expect. Howevever, if I enable `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_threading`, I get an error:

```
THREADING ERROR : object of type VkDeviceMemory is recursively used in thread 24812
```

If I instead just call `vkFlushMappedMemoryRanges` multiple times with only a single flush range, instead of an array, I don't get an error. Is flushing multiple sub-ranges of the same buffer not a valid use case?

Comment: Are you using multiple threads?

Comment: @NicolBolas There are multiple threads in the application, but only one thread ever calls Vulkan methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a false error report from the layer.  A single function call can safely refer to the same vulkan object several times.  Newer versions of the thread checking layer don't report that false conflict.  (That layer is renamed to VK_LAYER_GOOGLE_threading in recent versions.)